# How to configure Managed App Configuration in a Cordova app?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on an ionic-cordova app and I want to use AirWatch MDM to deploy the app: https://www.air-watch.com/faq/what-is-mdm

I see that there is a plugin for Cordova that might possibly help with this task:
https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences
but it doesn't say where to put the key-value pairs.

It seems inconvenient and unmaintainable to have to change the build files each time I do either an Android or an iOS build.

Is there a place I can put an XML file for this and do it automatically on each build?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** No.

I suggest using [Cordova AppConfig Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-emm-app-config) by Oracle to implement App configuration.

**iOS setup (easy):**
Handles the configuration via [Managed AppConfig](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/sc2279/Introduction/Intro.html). Just add the Key-value pairs in the assignment tab from AirWatch when you publish the app.

**Android (a bit harder):**
Android relies on [App Restrictions](https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations.html) so you'll need to edit the Android studio project (follow the instructions from the link).
The tricky part is that the key-value pairs must be *validated by google*. Thus you'll have to upload the ap to Google Play Store or to Android for Work private store to read them from the app.

**Common:** Read the values using the linked plugin (one line of code, see example in the plugin's page).

Comment: When it comes to the Application Configuration (Configuration Key,
Configuration Value) is that something that needs to be bundled with the app?

Comment: From Android's documentation:
_"Create a file named app_restrictions.xml in your app's res/xml directory. The structure of that file is described in the reference for RestrictionsManager."._

In that file you'll have a set of key-value pairs equal to those you set up in AirWatch (in assignment tab).